# meteor - How to update subscription documents?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I subscribe some collection from server. After I try to delete one document from client side it shows `remove failed: Access denied`. so I tried to delete it from server side by `Meteor.call` it works fine but client side has same number of documents.

Below code will explain you better.

**ClientJS:**

```
Template.Message.onCreated(function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('mymessage');
  }.bind(this));
});

Template.Message.onRendered(function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    if (this.subscription.ready()) {
      console.log(Message.find().count()); //10
     }
  }.bind(this));
});
```

**ServerJS:**

```
  Meteor.publish('mymessage', function() {
    console.log(Message.find().count()); //10
    return Message.find();
  });
```

In a click event

**ClientJS:**

```
Meteor.call("deletemsg", this._id._str, function(error, result){ 
 if(!error){
     console.log(Message.find().count()); // 10, Want to update document here.
   }
});
```

**Serverjs**

```
  Meteor.methods({
    deletemsg: function (delmsg) {
      if(Message.remove({"_id":new Mongo.ObjectID(delmsg)})){
       console.log(Message.find().count()); //9
       return true;
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error("some error message");
      }
     }
  });
```

Note : I am using existing Mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably related to your configuration of the native rules `allow` and `deny`. You should have somewhere on your server a piece of code looking like that (`Message` being your collection name):

```
Message.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        //allow rule
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        //allow rule
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        //allow rule
    }
});
```

Or an equivalent with `deny`. It looks like your current user is not allowed to delete (i.e. remove) messages from the collection.

Quick sidenote: you don't need to wrap your subscriptions in an `autorun`. If you use iron-router, you can use the built in functions to subscribe. In your routes options, you can add something like this:

```
action: function() {
    if(this.isReady()) { this.render(); } else { this.render("loading");}
},

isReady: function() {


    var subs = [
        Meteor.subscribe("yourPublication")
    ];
    var ready = true;
    _.each(subs, function(sub) {
        if(!sub.ready())
            ready = false;
    });
    return ready;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use _str as _id is already string.

> Client JS

```
Meteor.call("deletemsg", this._id, function(error, result){  //Remove _str from here
 if(!error){
     console.log(Message.find().count()); // 10, Want to update document here.
   }
});
```

> Server JS

When you delete document, you need to pass only id, not object.

```
 Meteor.methods({
    deletemsg: function (delmsg) {
      if(Message.remove(delmsg)){
       console.log(Message.find().count()); //9
       return true;
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error("some error message");
      }
     }
  });
```

> Allowing CRUD operations.

if above method doesnt work, try allowing CRUD operations for that collections from server block. [Here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) is documentation.